# Passing Values Between Activities Via Using Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I want my activity to pass a value to another activity class that extends view. Can you please tell me a solution? I am new to Android Programming.

Comment: You should be more clear.. which View are you extending.. and some more details

Answer (score 2):

Better idea is..

```
class CustomView extends View{
 YourData data;
public CustomView(YourData data, Context context){
this.data = data

}

}
```

and in Activity

```
new CustomView(data. this)
```

Answer (score 1):

pass throgh constructor or getter/seller . nothing related to android .
use standard java tequnique to pass data to object .

Answer (score 0):

you can't because intents are used to comunicate between activitys, receivers & services.

Comment: All the more reason they should be able to carry information around.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the activity reference in the view and use that to get the appropriate values.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    MyView v;
    int i;
    public void onCreate(){
         v = new MyView(this);
    }

} 

class MyView extends View {
    MyActivity activity;
    public MyView(MyActivity act) {
        this.activity = act;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        int valueFromActivity = activity.i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the main class (A.java)

```
  Intent i = new Intent(A.this,B.class);
                i.putExtra("val", the value that you want to pass);
                startActivity(i);
```

in B.java

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main2);
 Integer number = getIntent().getIntExtra("val", 0);
```

We will get the passes value in **number**